# Can not get the gender of the user: property 'gender' not found on object of type 'NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *'

Tags: ios, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk, fb-graph

This is my code to get the whole dictionary representing the user Graph:

```
 if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",user);//Displayed with the gender
                 NSLog(@"%@",user.name);//Name only displayed
                 NSLog(@"%@",user.gender);//Build error
             }
         }];
    }
```

I would love to know what's wrong with the gender data, and why it's not found in the dictionary, actually, i get a build error:

```
property 'gender' not found on object of type 'NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook is not sending gender in response of "requestForMe".
In order to get gender send request like this:

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,gender,name, whatever you like" forKey:@"fields"];

[[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%d",myUserId] parameters:params HTTPMethod:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:...
```

I am not sure but I think you can also as graph path set @"me" instead of user's id.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion, mine also works, and i could finally read the `gender` if i extract it normaly from the dictionary:              `NSLog(@"%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);`

Comment: In your suggestion, `NSLog(@"%@",user.gender);` is still causing the same build issue Though `NSLog(@"%@",user);` paste the whole dictionary with the gender field.

Answer (score 9):

you can use `[user objectForKey:@"gender"];`